Use nuget package in node-gyp project
I am working on a node application that requires working with C++ libraries to access specific apis. To do this I am using node-gyp to compile my c++ code.
I have a basic "hello world" build of the c++ code working and am working on integrating with the c++ libraries I need to use. The libraries are part of a nuget package. Is there a way to update my binding.gyp file to be able to include dependencies from a nuget package?
